upper limit of probability function with small sample size
Given $X$ is a worker salary $\mathbb{E}[\bar{X}] = 10,000$ and $\sigma = 5,000$:

Taken a random sample of $10$ people, is it possible that
$$
P\left\{8,000 \le \bar{X} \le 12,000\right\} = 0.3\ ?.
$$
I tried using the Central Limit Theorem but from what I understand it is for "big" sample sizes.


What is the distribution?

$Var(\bar{X}) = 5000$ looks as if it is worth checking. Are you sure it is the variance rather than the standard deviation? Is it supposed to be the variance of the sample mean $\bar X$ or of $X$ the salary of an individual?

@Henry yes sorry that is standard deviation I edited my question also I translated from my language but the wording in my own language confuses, the exact translation is: a worker's salary distributes with expectation of 10,000 and a standard deviation of 5,000
is it possible that $P{8,000\le\bar{X}\le12,000}=0.3$?
is it better to post it like that?

You can estimate the probability of $\frac{(\bar{X} - \mu)}{\sigma}$ if you want, but the error will be pretty high, I guess.

Apply Chebyshev's inequality? The question ask "Is it possible..." so either we disprove that statement, or construct an example distribution satisfying the conditions.

Suppose $X$ had a normal distribution with mean $10000$ and standard deviation $5000$ (it does not, as normal distributions can be negative, but ignore this for the time being).  Then  for an individual: $\mathbb P\left(8,000 \le X \le 12,000\right) \approx 0.3108$.  But for a sample sized $10$: $\mathbb P\left(8,000 \le \bar{X} \le 12,000\right) \approx 0.7941$. So $\mathbb P\left(8,000 \le X \le 12,000\right) = 0.3$ is plausible for a close-to-normal distribution for an individual, but $\mathbb P\left(8,000 \le \bar{X} \le 12,000\right) =0.3$ is less plausible for the sample mean.

That does not answer whether it is impossible or possible for the sample mean with a particularly distorted distribution.  @BGM's suggestion of Chebyshev's inequality will not quite prove it is impossible, but I cannot see an easy way of construct an example where it is possible, and my guess is that it may be impossible for the mean of a sample sized $10$.

Since $E[X] = 10000, SD[X] = 5000$, $\displaystyle SD[\bar{X}_n] = \frac {5000} {\sqrt{n}}$
Then
$$ \begin{align} \Pr\{8000 \leq \bar{X}_{10} \leq 12000\} 
&= \Pr\{|\bar{X}_{10} - 10000| < 2000\} + \Pr\{|\bar{X}_{10} - 10000| = 2000\} \\
&\geq \Pr\{|\bar{X}_{10} - 10000| < 2000\} \\
&= 1 -  \Pr\left\{|\bar{X}_{10} - 10000| \geq 
\underbrace {\frac {2000 \times \sqrt{10}} {5000} }_{k}
\times \underbrace {\frac {5000} {\sqrt{10}}}_{\sigma}\right\} \\
&\geq 1 - \underbrace{\frac {5^2} {2^2 \times 10}}_{1/k^2} \\
&= \frac {3} {8} = 0.375 > 0.3
\end{align} 
 $$
where the last inequality follows from the Chebyshev's inequality
$$ \Pr\{|X - \mu| \geq k\sigma\} \leq \frac {1} {k^2} $$
Note that here the Chebyshev's inequality require to include the equality, so we need to change to strict inequality first before taking the complement.
So it is not possible for the equality holds.

why did you add the $\frac{2000\times\sqrt{10}}{5000}\times \frac{5000}{\sqrt{10}}$?

This is to demonstrate how we are going to apply the Chebyshev's inequality.
